# Getting count of entities over range in Berkeley db je database

Tags: database, time-series, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I have a Berkeley DB JE database with a lot of time series data. I would like to be able to count the number of items over a time range without having to iterate over them. Is this possible?